# Asy Problems of a newbie

Tags: pdftex, asymptote

I am new to latex. i try to insert the asymptote code on texstudio. It doesn't show anything. I have installed the asymptote and ghostscript

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you try running on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ ?